# Find longest comment line in a file in C

Tags: c

So I have this function to find the longest line in a file:

```
int LongestLine(FILE *filename) {

  char buf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};

  char line_val[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};
  int line_len = -1;
  int line_num = -1;
  int cur_line = 1;

  filename = fopen(filename, "r");

  while(fgets(buf, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, filename) != NULL) {
    int len_tmp = strlen(buf) - 1;

    if(buf[len_tmp] == '\n')
      buf[len_tmp] = '\0';

    if(line_len < len_tmp) {
      strncpy(line_val, buf, len_tmp + 1);
      line_len = len_tmp;
      line_num = cur_line;
    }

    cur_line++;
  }

  return line_num;
}
```

and I was thinking of combining it with this one:

```
bool startsWith(const char *pre, const char *str)
{
    size_t lenpre = strlen(pre),
           lenstr = strlen(str);
    return lenstr < lenpre ? false : strncmp(pre, str, lenpre) == 0;
}
```

But.. however, the `LongestLine()` function returns an integer. So how can I use both functions so that I may find the longest line starting with let's say `//`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a call to `startsWith` (to see if it is a comment) in your `if` statement to decide if a line is the new longest:

```
if( startsWith("//",buf) && (line_len < len_tmp) ) {
```

Comment: In which `if` statement? Or more precisely where?

Comment: @schmitsz: you're allowed to think, but the test for 'is it the longest line' is `if(line_len < len_tmp) {` so you need to alter that to also check for 'starts with'.

Comment: Yes, I tried that already. It returns -1 and not the number of the line. Actually wait. I was checking for "//" and not " //". My bad. You can submit it as an answer so I can accept it :)